# Sass rule not applying

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get styles to apply to specific nested divs and they aren't showing up. (This is the problem)

I would like for them to work, or in other words, to apply the rules. (This is the desired outcome)

HTML:

```
  <div class="" id="indexWrap">

    <!-- Features Section -->
    <section id="features" class="section-light">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            Stuff
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- END Features Section -->
  </div>
  <!-- END indexWrap -->
```

SCSS: (Also Bootstrap style sheet.)

```
  #indexwrap {  

    .col {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 8px;
      padding: 5px;
    }

  }
```

Order of styles

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

And here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avvbxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selectors are case sensitive:

`#indexwrap` should be `#indexWrap` to match the HTML's `id="indexWrap"`.

[Codepen Update](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYYjqQ)

Comment: Thank both of you! I can't believe I was looking at every complicated fix and I missed the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your container `div` has an ID of `indexWrap`, but you refer to it as `#indexwrap` in your SCSS. Make sure that you match the case of the identifier.